# iText vs Adobe livecycle pros and cons

Tags: itext

We need to decide a technology for PDF generation in our application. Client wants either iText or Adobe livecycle along with server.
I know Adobe can use reusable PDF templates for different kinds of products which might make it more kind of reusable at the time of new product on-boarding however with iText, we have to write lots of Java code to do same thing. However itext has more control over dynamic display of pages/tables/fields in my opinion which comes very handy in some cases compared to Adobe.
Apart from it, I am seeking opinion from experts for more concrete comparison of these 2 technologies with pros and cons on each other. I found very limited source for direct comparison over internet hence it can be useful for larger audience

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. See bullet 4 in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This being said, please be aware that Adobe LiveCycle templates are based on the XML Forms Architecture (XFA), and that XFA was deprecated in ISO 32000-2. See bullet 1 under deprecations on the [PDF 2.0 page](https://www.pdfa.org/intro/pdf-2-0-the-worldwide-standard-for-electronic-documents-has-evolved/) by the PDF Association. With iText, you can "code" your document, but you can also use HTML as a template, and soon we'll release a templating solution: http://dito.online/

Comment: This link might also be useful: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml *Writing lots of Java code to do the same thing* isn't always necessary. (Provided that you use iText 7 and not some old version of iText.)

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Yes I was referring to older version of itext 2 and 5 which we had used earlier.

Comment: Well, iText 2 has many technical and even legal flaws: https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5 And iText 5 is being phased out: it's no longer supported except for paying customers. iText 7 is a complete rewrite of iText with the same license as iText 5. You should consider upgrading to iText 7.

Comment: If you consider using iText 2.X take a look at https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF. There is no general answer to your question since we don't know your requirements. What do you want to do with PDF? If it is only PDF generation you might also take a look at Apache FOP. If you use Open Source solutions like iText you'll definitly need 1 or 2 developers who know what they are doing (Implementing, Fixing bugs etc.) With ALC you buy a product (not so much coding) but the price for ALC (at least in the past) was very, very high... So do your own analysis because nobody can do it better than you.

Comment: Thanks Lonzak for suggestion. Requirement is that pdf needs to be generated for different products in different languages and there could be some similarity between some products. Hence some customization is expected for every new product.So far I believe Adobe livcycle could be good choice between these 2 technologies